# How to validate a chatbot?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, chatbot

Let's say I'm building a medical assistance chatbot.

How do I validate that my model is working well or better than others.

Is there any standard validation metrics for it ?

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to answer this question because you have not defined what *precisely* you want your chatbot to do (and not to do!). Once you have defined that, you have your metric.

So the answer to your second question is: no, there is no standard validation metric.